# C# Fill array values in just one line of code

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm adding value to an array of bytes with the following code:

```
byte[] ConnectionPath;


ConnectionPath[0] = 0;
ConnectionPath[1] = 2;
ConnectionPath[2] = 1;
ConnectionPath[3] = 0;
```

My question is, can't I do this in just 1 line of code? I tried this, but this doesn't work. (I know that you can do this by declaration, but of course this value changes through the program)

```
ConnectionPath = { 0, 2, 1, 0};
```

Comment: `byte[] ConnectionPath = { 0, 2, 1, 0};` does work, but you need to do it at the point of declaration

Comment: If you need to split declaration and initialization then `ConnectionPath = new byte[]{ 0, 2, 1, 0};` works

Comment: I know that you can do it at the point of declaration, but that is useless in my application, because the values changes a couple of times during the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do it all in one line this works:

```
byte[] ConnectionPath = { 0, 2, 1, 0 };
```

otherwise you have to tell the compiler what type of array it is:

```
byte[] ConnectionPath;
ConnectionPath = new byte[]{ 0, 2, 1, 0 };
```